# Wizard form in sharepoint doesn't show all views in display form

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, infopath

Following [this article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/introduction-to-views-HA010156628.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010285356) I've created a form for a sharepoint list with multiple views and I switch between them using a button with a rule. It all works fine while creating or editing an item.

If I try to view an item I'm only shown the first view and since this view now is read only, the button I use to switch views is not there anymore.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify to show a different view in different pages (like NewIFS.aspx, DisplayIFS.aspx, EditIFS.aspx)

Navigate to a webpage in a browser.
On ribbon click List (under List Tools)--? Click "Site Actions" --> "Edit page"--? on design surface on the right of Infopath Form Web Part an arrow on upper right side --> Edit Web Part --> under "Selected View:" drop-down box select a view to be shown on this web page

[image]